# Flip a SpriteNode with SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am making a game and I have 20 textures, that has to be flipped dynamically(like a mirror). I tried to use node.xScale = node.xScale *-1 and node.yScale = node.yScale *-1 but it doesn't work.. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a problem description, more so because this (negating scale) has been proven to work (flip sprites)

Comment: The node still in the same scale, and doesn't flip..

Comment: It may help if you post a picture of the texture.

Comment: I am using SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture (from atlas using SKTextureAtlas).
Picture of the texture(and many more like this house): [link](http://prntscr.com/4u041q)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D do you have any idea?Thanks

Comment: You need to post the actual code, as this definitely works. Are you sure that elsewhere in the code you aren't setting the scale ? Also, if for some reason that code gets called twice, it'll flip back.

Comment: I'd also suggest you just github the project, as there's not much else that anyone can say. It definitely works, so you likely have a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Weird that it doesn't work. I believe simple doing `node.xScale = -1` works as you want to keep the scale factor the same (1) and inverse it. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: No, It still doesn't work.. The node still in the same scale, and doesn't flip..Even I am setting up a break point and print the value it prints -1, but it still not flipped..

Comment: I just tried it myself and it worked fine. Are you using a texture, or an image, or a plain colour? Also, what version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: I am using SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture (from atlas using SKTextureAtlas). I am using Xcode 6.1.

Comment: Unfortunately i only have Xcode 6.0 so can't tell you whether it is a change in the new Xcode. The only thing i can think of it that because you are using a texture, it textures the inverse exactly the same giving the illusion that it is not actually being flipped. id be interested to know if using SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "") gives the same problem.

Comment: But I'm using SKTextureAtlas because I'm using an atlas file. So it's a texture no?
 SKTextureAtlas *atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"Houses"];
object = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[atlas textureNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"house%d",arc4random_uniform(20)+1]]];

Comment: I tried now without an atlas film and it still doesn't work..
object = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"house%d",arc4random_uniform(20)+1]];
object.yScale *= -1.0;

Comment: Im lost for ideas then. Ill have to leave it for someone else to answer I'm afraid, also, you should be doing `object.yScale = -1` and not `object.yScale *= -1`